# Countries select menu using material ui

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I mapped through an Array of strings with countries names , mapped through it , to get a dropdown menu list of all countries in my form , but the select dropdown doesnt work .. am i doing something wrong?

```
<FormControl fullWidth style={{ marginTop: "1.2rem" }}>
          <InputLabel variant="standard" htmlFor="uncontrolled-native">
            Select A Country
          </InputLabel>
          <NativeSelect
            defaultValue={1}
            inputProps={{
              name: "country",
              id: "uncontrolled-native",
            }}
          >
            {countryList.map((country, index) => {
              <option value={index + 1} key={index}>
                {country}
              </option>;
            })}
          </NativeSelect>
        </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you missing the return in the map, you should use it like this:

```js
{countryList.map((country, index) => {
    return <option value={index + 1} key={index}>
               {country}
           </option>;
})}
```

Or you can try my full code:

```js
<FormControl fullWidth style={{ marginTop: "1.2rem" }}>
    <InputLabel variant="standard" htmlFor="uncontrolled-native">
        Select A Country
    </InputLabel>
    <NativeSelect defaultValue={1} inputProps={{
                      name: "country",
                      id: "uncontrolled-native"}}>
                   {countryList.map((country, index) => {
                       return <option value={index + 1} key={index}>
                                  {country}
                              </option>;
                    })}
    </NativeSelect>
</FormControl>
```